# Object search on part of the array

Tags: c++, algorithm, search, binary-search

I have object like this:

```
class search_object
{
public:
    unsigned int index; // 0 <= index <= 50000
    unsigned int search_field; // 1 <= search_field <= 5000000000, can be duplicates!
};
```

I have approximately `50000` objects such type. These objects sorted by index.

My program gets search queries like this: "is there some object, which have index between `left_index` and `right_index` (`left_index <= index <= right_index`) and have `search_field` eqaul to `Number` (`search_field == Number`).

There are approximately `50000` queries.

I have solution, but it is slow for my context system.

My algorithm is:

1. Sort search objects by `search_field`.
2. Find `lower_index`, where `search_object[lower_index] = Number` (`lower_bound()` function, it is a binary search)
3. Iterate over array of objects from `lower_index` to the end of the array. If `this_object` has `index` between `left_index` and `right_index`, then `true`. Otherwise, `false`.
4. Repeat steps `2-3` for all search queries (left_index, right_index and Number).

Comment: You could sort the objects by `index` instead, then iterate over the range `[left_index, right_index]` and check if any of them fulfills `search_filed == Number`.

Comment: Have you considered using SQL?

Comment: @The Paramagnetic Croissant, I tried this way. It is slow for my context system too.

Comment: @Christian Hackl, I can not use SQL, because it is study task.

Comment: Do you really sort each time as start of the algorithm?  If the container is already sorted by index, then I wouldn't know how you can get faster then the way @TheParamagneticCroissant suggests.

Comment: @stefaanv, I sort my objects 1 time (before performing search queries). The solution of TheParamagneticCroissant fails on 11 test, and my algorithm get fail on 17 test.

Comment: use map<int, int*>, key is search_field, value is the the sorted array of indices that the search_field occurs. it costs some time to preprocess.when you do query, first, get value, then apply binary search

Answer (score 0):

I would use a standard container, I would not use the object itself as a key. Code example:

```
std::map<decltype(search_object::index), search_object> container;

...

auto itr = container.lower_bound(left_index);

while (itr != container.end() && itr->first <= right_index)
  if (itr->second == Number) return itr;

return container.end();
```

Comment: Unfortunately, It is slow for my context system too.

Comment: you are running `-O2` optimized version, yeah?

Comment: @bodah, nope. It is context system, I am not able set up any flags.

Comment: what is "context system"?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `map<unsigned int, list<search_object*>>` which holds a list of your objects for every search_field.

Comment: I tried this way. Unfortunately, It is slow for my context system too.

Answer (score 0):

With the right sort strategy before the search it can be done easily.

```
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <algorithm>    // std::lower_bound, std::upper_bound, std::sort
#include <vector>       // std::vector

class search_object
{
public:
    uint64_t index; // 0 <= index <= 50000
    uint64_t search_field; // 1 <= search_field <= 5000000000, can be duplicates!
};

search_object data[] = { { 13, 54345632 }, { 42, 4645347 }, { 63, 4645347 }, { 117, 4674534536 } };

using table = std::vector<search_object>;
using itr = table::const_iterator;
using range = std::pair<itr, itr>;

template<typename Pred>
range FindRange(const table& vec, Pred pred, search_object lowValue, search_object highValue) {
  // concept vec is sorted by pred
  //assert(pred(lowValue, highValue)); // paranoid check

  itr low=std::lower_bound (vec.begin(), vec.end(), lowValue, pred); //
  itr up= std::upper_bound (low,         vec.end(), highValue, pred); // no reason to search before low!

  return range(low, up);
}

int main () {
  std::vector<search_object> FldTable(std::begin(data),std::end(data));

  // sort by primary key field and secondary index.
  auto CmpFld = [] (const search_object& obj1, const search_object& obj2) {
    return obj1.search_field < obj2.search_field || // primary sort
           ((obj1.search_field == obj2.search_field) && // secondary
        (obj1.index < obj2.index)
       );
  };

  // sort after field
  std::sort (FldTable.begin(), FldTable.end(), CmpFld); // dublicates possible.

  // some "random" search values
  unsigned int lowSearchIndex = 10, highSearchIndex = 100, searchField = 4645347;

  search_object low { lowSearchIndex,  searchField };
  search_object up  { highSearchIndex, searchField };
  range search = FindRange(FldTable, CmpFld, low, up);

  for (itr record = search.first; record < search.second; ++record)
     std::cout << "index = " << record->index << " field = " << record-> search_field << "\n";

  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
index = 42 field = 4645347
index = 63 field = 4645347
```

> > std::upper_bound
> >     Returns an iterator pointing to the first element in the range [first,last) which compares greater than val.

Comment: why you use `search_object up = { highSearchIndex, searchField+1 }`, not `{ highSearchIndex, searchField};`?

Comment: Yesterday, I tried this way. Unfortunately, It is slow for my context system too.